# Expanding compressed div

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8MUF/

It can expand the div when i click on it. How do i make it look nicer by adding a "See More" link then hide it when the div exapands and adjust the row height relative to the See More link?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var rowsshown = 2;
 var rowheight = 1.2; // line height in 'em'
 var ht = (rowsshown * rowheight) - .5; // subtracting the .5 prevents the top of the next line from showing
 $('.info')
  .css({'overflow':'hidden','line-height' : rowheight + 'em','height': ht + 'em' })
  .click(function(){
   if ( $(this).css('height') == 'auto') {
    $(this).css('height', ht + 'em');
   } else {
    $(this).css('height','auto');
   }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8MUF/11/

Comment: i have them in a loop, what should I do? When i click on see more the rest of the others also expand.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the jquery slideup and slidedown 
http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

For a better effect